# Ordenar las publicaciones en RecyclerView por numero de likes que cada una tiene

Tags: java, android

Quiero poner en orden por número más grande al número más pequeño los posts que tengo en Firebase. Estoy haciendo una búsqueda para ver los likes que tiene cada publicación y quiero ponerlas en orden del post que tiene más likes hasta el que menos likes tiene.

He pensado que podría hacerlo con getChildrenCount() que me devuelve el número de likes de cada publicación, pero luego no sé cómo ordenarlas...

Lo estoy haciendo así, pero no sé si está bien o no, o si hay mejor forma de hacerlo. Cómo lo puedo hacer?

**TrendingFragment**

```
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private PostAdapter mPostAdapter;
private List<Post> mPostList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mPostList = new ArrayList<>();
    mPostAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mPostList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);

    readPosts();

    return view;
}

private void readPosts() {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("count");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            mPostList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                if (post != null) {
                    mPostList.add(post);
                }
            }

            mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Post> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Post o1, Post o2) {
        return o1.getCount().compareTo(o2.getCount());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la interface [Comparator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/) para ordendar tus posts con Collections.sort. el método compareTo() es para comparar Strings y devuelve un entero dependientdo si la cadena va antes o después en orden alfabetico, sí tus datos son numéricos puedes devolver una resta de ambos como entero.

```
class SortByLikes implements Comparator<Post> 
{ 
    public int compare(Post o1, Post o2) 
    { 
        return Long.compare(o2.getCount(), o1.getCount());
    } 
}
```

Cuando termines de agregar todos los posts a tu lista puedes ordenarla de la siguiente forma

```
Collections.sort(mPostList,new SortByLikes())
```

Después de eso puedes crear o actualizar tua adapter

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tío. El único problema aquí, porque lo he pensado y creo que estaría bien también guardar el número de Likes con las publicaciones también, pero el problema con este método es que no  puedo comparar valores que no sean Strings. Y los números los guardo en la base de datos como long y no como Strings. He actualizado el código. Podrías echarle un vistazo y decirme cómo lo puedo modificar?

Comment: He intentado a hacerlo como dices tú, pero es que el Comparator no puede, creo... comparar dos valores que no sean Strings, verdad?

Comment: El compareTo() es para comparar strings, en el caso de Comparator.compare() debes retornar un valor mayor, menor o igual que 0 dependiendo de las reglas que definas para la comparación. Ya actualicé mi respuesta para que puedas probar.